# Changing the value of a var imported from another file, without affecting the original values in runtime memory

Tags: python, variables, scope, namespaces

So, i have two file;
utils.py
and
globals.py.

globals.py holds some variables in it, core.py has an install() function.

Inside of this function i need to modify the variables from globals.py, but without directly effecting the values saved inside of globals.py.

I need a way of leaving the code untouched so that its still using globals.var, but just change the content of the var for the current function ONLY when edition is True.

⠀

**Code below doesnt work in the way i want but is good practice**

**globals.py**

```py
spotify = "original_url"
```

**core.py**

```py
import globals
async def install(edition=False):
  if edition:
    globals.spotify = "new_url"

utils.chunked_download(globals.spotify)
```

**other.py** (RAN AFTER THE INSTALL)

```py
import globals
# Now that the install has been run with edition=True, these globals are now changed for all scripts
print(globals.spotify)
```

> `returns new_url instead of original_url`

⠀

**Code below works in the way i want but is bad practice**

**core.py**

```py
from globals import *
async def install(edition=False):
  if edition:
    spotify = "new_url"

utils.chunked_download(spotify)
```

**other.py** (RAN AFTER THE INSTALL)

```py
import globals
print(globals.spotify)
```

> `Returns the original value "original_url" like i want`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean when you say you want to modify the variables "globally, but self contained within the function". Could you clarify please?

Comment: I think i've updated it in a way that makes more sense and given a 'working' example for what i need to achieve.